# Test flakiness in Katalon Studio

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-design, katalon

I'm having a problem but I'm not sure what is the cause.

When I run a test case that includes an **iframe** object, on the first run **Katalon** is finding the iframe but unable to click an object inside of the frame. After leaving everything as is (I'm not changing anything in the script) and just re-running the test, the object in question is found and the test passes. There are **no dynamic locators** or anything similar involved.

I looked at the [Automated test flakiness](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18417/automated-test-flakiness) but I didn't recognize a solution to my problem. Did anyone face a similar issue?

*Alternatively*, is there a way to run the same test twice, under condition that the first one fails?

Comment: do you have any alert message in the scenario

Comment: It is usually the "element not clickable" message, e.g.: Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button .....>...</button> is not clickable at point (1878, 902). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>

Comment: Which browser and its version you are using?

Comment: It's Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

> Wait For Element Not Visible

For this element `<div class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>`

It appears on the front-end  most probably when there is some back end operation running and disappears when the operation is finished.

You maybe have to add some delay of 1 or 2 seconds before the above step if the test persist to fail from time to time.

Comment: This will take out some of the test flakiness.

Comment: I used `Wait For Element Not Present` for element selected by css selector `'.ui-widget-overlay'`.
`Wait For Element Not Visible` throws a stale element exception.

My app has the overlay used for every dialog box, form or iframe opened. So this seems to reduce flakiness by a good amount. ***knocks on wood***